# how to prevent scrollHeight in div reload in php JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make live chat and I'am using this JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // load messages every 1000 milliseconds from server.
 load_data = {'fetch':1};
 window.setInterval(function(){
  $.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
  $('.message_box').html(data);
  var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
  $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
  });
 }, 1000);

 //method to trigger when user hits enter key
 $("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
  if(evt.which == 13) {
    var iusername = $('#shout_username').val();
    var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
    post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};

    //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
    $.post('shout.php', post_data, function(data) {

     //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
     $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

     //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
     var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
     $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);

     //reset value of message box
     $('#shout_message').val('');

    }).fail(function(err) {

    //alert HTTP server error
    alert(err.statusText);
    });
   }
 });

 //toggle hide/show shout box
 $(".close_btn").click(function (e) {
  //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
  var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');

  //toggle show/hide chat box
  $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

  //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
  if(toggleState == 'block')
  {
   $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btn');
  }else{
   $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btn');
  }


 });
});
```

Source: https://www.sanwebe.com/assets/chat-shout-box/

And my problem is, because Im using 
`var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);`, it always scroll to bottom every time page has reloaded.

What I am trying to do is it will only scroll to bottom when someone sent a new chat. just like in facebook.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```js
 // load messages every 1000 milliseconds from server.
 load_data = {'fetch':1};
 window.setInterval(function(){
  $.post('shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
  $('.message_box').html(data);
  //var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight; //try to replace this in other place just play with the code
  //$('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
  });
 }, 1000);
```

Hope this help at least a little.

Plus this code:

```js
function chatFunc(){
 setTimeout(function() {
   //your code to be executed after 1 second
  var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
  $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
 }, 1000);
}
window.onload = chatFunc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the only problem is it wont scroll to bottom when you are not using the chat. but I try to fix it